# react vr how to locate any item behind the scene

Tags: reactjs, react-360

I am so new sorry about this question how to put plane behinf the camera view ?

transform feature moves item at 2d platform not 3d any solution to this

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

By setting a positive 3rd argument to the translation you can get stuff to show up behind the camera. All objects start out at `0, 0, 0` coordinates (x, y, z axis). You can read more about this in the official docs for [3D Coordinates and Transforms](https://facebook.github.io/react-vr/docs/3dcoordinates-and-transforms.html).

```
<Text style={{
      backgroundColor: '#777879',
      fontSize: 0.8,
      layoutOrigin: [0.5, 0.5],
      transform: [{translate: [0, 0, 1]}],
    }}>This is a test!</Text>
```